# Error on flagging posts, after browser update

Tags: support, flags, error-message

Have just tried flagging a post (actually tried 3 different ones) but I keep getting an error dialog on submission

> An error occurred during submission

[image]

I did just update my browser to FF4 if that makes a difference, any ideas or just a glitch

**Update:** I just found another post to flag :p (I don't make a habit of it honest!)- it still didn't work in FF4, but did in Safari, so I guess that's my answer, but what's changed does anyone know of add-on conflicts or prefs settings - I don't really think I'd be popular if I disabled all add-ons and spent all day trying to flag posts, re-enabling them one by one

**Update 2**: still occurring in FireFox 4 - I have cleared cache and disabled all extensions, does work in Safari (didn't test anything else to not annoy mods!)

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Octavian tried again same error.. have added screenshot

Comment: "Did you clear your cache?"

Comment: @Jeff just tried that with no joy, later after work I'll try disabling some add-ons thanks.

Comment: also, what does firebug say?

Comment: @waffles, `GET http://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/messages/inform-moderator-about-post/94443 500 Internal Server Error 352ms`