# flagging does not work today?

Tags: support, flags

Since some weeks, I have (on Stack Overflow) the access to the moderator tools. One symptom of this is that I sometimes get a orange marker in the head line, like this:

[image: "We have posts flagged for moderator attention, perhaps you can help"].

Since I'm a very helpful person, I then click this link and look at some of the flagged posts. I I find one I want to flag, too, I'm using the flag button, and come to the usual flagging GUI:

[image: "I'm flagging because ..."]

Then clicking the button, I just get this result (after some seconds of waiting):

[image: "an error occurred"]

This repeats for every flag I'm trying to do, and also from the normal question pages.

Is this a temporary bug (but then how comes 68 flags from other persons got collected?), something wrong with my account or my browser/OS configuration (Opera 11.11 on Ubuntu)? I did flags before, this problem just started recently.

Comment: same here, different Browser/OS also reported but still no joy fixing:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94443/error-on-flagging-posts-after-browser-update

Comment: I can't see anything in the log ... does this work in firefox? if not what does firebug say?

Comment: It seems to work in Firefox, yes (and still does not work in Opera). (But I don't want to work with Firefox for my normal surfing.)

Comment: Flagging comments works, though.

Comment: odd ... I am on 11.11 windows and it works, have you dumped you cache?

Comment: I just cleared the cookies and the cache, closed the browser, waited some minutes, restarted it, logged in again, tried to flag something - no chance, still the same problem :-(  (I will try on another system after getting some sleep now.)

Comment: Okay. On Opera 11.11 on SUSE Linux (on another system and IP) it works. Looks like I will only flag from here, and not at home.

Comment: Hmm, now it seems to work again from home. I'm not sure what changed - my Opera version is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I was home earlier and tried it again, and now it seems to work again.

I have no idea what changed (my Opera version is still the same, maybe something changed at Stack Overflow), but there is nothing left to worry.

(I'm answering so this question can be marked closed.)